# Drupal statistics does not count visits when I see the node from a custom panel

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, statistics, panels

I have a web site where each node has three diferents designs (i do it through panels and arguments) and i use the statistics module, that way i can see how many visits has the node.

But the statistics module jus count the visits when they visit the main design. I can explain with a example:

- website .com/node/01 <---when a user visit this url, a visit is counted
- website .com/node/01/mobile <----- here is not counted the visit
- website .com/node/01/lightbox <----here is not counted the visit

This was built for panels and arguments... so, is there anyway to put a php code in two panels that visitors don't have to start to count?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

It's because panels doesn't invoke node_view(). Please try following code:

```
function MODULE_ctools_render_alter(&$info, &$page, &$context) {
  if ($context['handler']->task == 'node_view') {
    $key = $context['handler']->conf['context'];
    $node = $context['contexts'][$key]->data;
    statistics_node_view($node, 'full')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use node [views count module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount)

> Node View Count module allows to count node views. Unlike statistics
>   module, this module records each view of node with user uid and
>   timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by
>   day, week, month and etc.
>
> This module is integrated with Views module. You can use it to create
>   different statistics pages, output new not viewed nodes for user and
>   many more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I make Panel Page work with Statistics:

```
    function MODULE_ctools_render_alter(&$info, &$page, &$context) {
      if (!user_is_logged_in() && $context['handler']->task == 'node_view') {
        $node = current($context['contexts'])->data;
        statistics_node_view($node, 'full');
        drupal_process_attached($node->content);
      }
    }
```

I add a user_is_logged_in check, because in my case I just wanted to count the hits from not logged users.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Drupal 8.

```
function MODULE_panels_build_alter(array &$build, $panels_display) {
        if ($nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node')) {
                $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'statistics/drupal.statistics';
                $settings = ['data' => ['nid' => $nid], 'url' => \Drupal::request()->getBasePath() . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'statistics') . '/statistics.php'];
                $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['statistics'] = $settings;
        }   
}
```